# Bootstrap active tab shown event listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, show

I'm using Bootstrap Tabs and I have one default tab that has active class on page load. When I want to apply some jQuery effects with animation on that tab's content (for example 'show(2000)') that content does not show for 2 seconds, but instantly jumps in after this 2 s time. So jQuery works, but only partially - u cant see animation.

I tried to analyze the cause of this problem. It seems that when bootstrap is loading active tab some it's machinery is still working after the page load and not allowing jQuery 'show' method to get all element's properties at start of animation. So jQuery gets for example opacity but not width and height of element. If I setTimeout on 'show' animation for something about 150-200ms everything is working ok.

Another problem is, that U cant set shown.bs.tab listener on active tab, loaded by default.

Did U have similar problems, and how u managed to resolve it in the easiest way possible?

I was thinking about not setting active class but managing to click or show tabs by JavaScript, allowing to shown.bs listener to work and then apply my jQuery on callback. Another ideas?

Comment: Try to make sure the document is fully loaded before running your script: `$(window).on("load", function() { /* your code goes here */ });`

Comment: blex - thanks, but still not working :( It would be too ez ;)